# Conditional Rendering of Props (no re-render)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am importing some mock data which is organised as an array in `productData.js`. This is being passed as a prop into `TableComponent`. However, if conditional rendering is not used (`props.productData && ...`) I get `Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`. From my reading, this is because `render` is called before the props are received asynchronously.

However, with the example below, the page is re-rendered when `productData` is imported. I have checked in the React Developer Tool and TableComponent does contain `props.ProductData` which is the array just as I expected.

Why does the page not re-render with the data?

```
import productData from './productData.js'
...
const MainBody = () => {
  return (
    <TableComponent>
      productData={productData}
    </TableComponent>
  );
}

const TableComponent = props => { 
  const rows = props.productData && props.productData.map((row, index) => {
    return (
      <tr>
        <row>{row}</row>
      </tr>
    );
  });
  return <tbody>{rows}</tbody>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<TableComponent>
  productData={productData}
</TableComponent>
```

thats a TableComponent with no props and a text inside saying `productData={productData}`. You probably wanted:

```
<TableComponent productData={productData} >
</TableComponent>
```